# How to make getElementById work in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML and the script

```
 <script>  $(document).ready(function(){  
 $(".update_button").click(function(){ 

 var update_post = $("#post").val();
 alert('Post is '+ update_post +'.');
 return false;
 });
 });
 </script>

 <body>
     <fieldset style="width:600px; height:550px">
       <textarea id="post" class="uiwysiwyg nothing"><?php echo $prvpost; ?></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="Post" id="updt_button" class="update_button"/>
     </fieldset> </body>
```

Note: class="uiwysiwyg nothing" is a script the contains the WYSIWYG commands

But code works:

```
 <body onsubmit="alert('Update: ' + document.getElementById('post').value); return false;">
     <fieldset style="width:600px; height:550px">
       <textarea id="post" class="uiwysiwyg nothing"><?php echo $prvpost; ?></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="Post" id="updt_button" class="update_button"/>
     </fieldset>
 </body>
```

Comment: @simon says that a textarea has no value. it should be on html() or text()

Comment: did you have a look at the jsfiddle link i posted in my post . val() does work for textarea jquery

Comment: What exactly is the output of <?php echo $prvpost; ?>?

Comment: i have tried it and applied but the problem is that tags are not captured like <b> </b> <i> </i> and i also found out that when applying <?php ?> in textarea it would just give me [object][Object]

Comment: @Alice: It's pretty strange, my first guess (comment I already deleted), was that the content of textarea is HTML and that it gets converted to a jQuery object through .val(), but nonetheless it puts out the text for me, no matter if .val() .html() .text() is used...

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by this "class="uiwysiwyg nothing" is a script the contains the WYSIWYG commands" ...

Comment: it is a script for the WYSIWYG. it is when you need to bold, italic or insert link.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var update_post = $("#post").val();
alert(update_post);
```

Comment: yes it was ID not a class sorry. I have changed it from . to # but it still doesn't work.

this is the original where all the WYSIWYG feature is working. It captures all the html formats

> onsubmit="alert('You said:\n\n' +
> document.getElementById('post').value); return false;

but when i try it using

> var update_post = $("#post").val();

it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

By using $(.post) you are using something like document.getElementByClass... If you want document.getElementById please use $("#post)...and yes please check  jquery Selectors

Edit:- Your code is fine.. just checked it  at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rkc7/)

Comment: i also have same idea with as yours.

i have tried this. but it's not functioning

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".update_button").click(function(){
var update_post = $("#post").val();
alert(update_post);
}

it just gives me a result of: "[object Object]"

Comment: Can i please look at what is the element with the post id. I mean can you post the html too

Comment: Just to note: there is document.getElementsByClassName in JS

Comment: @alice here is the HTML and the script

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".update_button").click(function(){ 

  var update_post = $("#post").val();         
  alert('Post is '+ update_post +'.');         
  return false;
  });
 });
</script>

<body>
    <fieldset style="width:600px; height:550px">
      <textarea id="post" class="uiwysiwyg nothing"><?php echo $prvpost; ?></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Post" id="updt_button" class="update_button"/>
    </fieldset>
</body>

Comment: @user1497888: update your question with corrected/new code snippets instead of posting them in the comments.

Comment: @Simon Corrected my post.. long time since I used Javascript

Comment: @Simon. in **document.getElementById** is there no way to pass it to **$(#post).val** ?

Comment: @user1497888 I sincerely dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the first example you're using `post` as an id.
In the second example you're using it as a css class (`.post`).
The second example should be `#post`.

Check out [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

i assume "post" is ID not CSS class, so you have to use "#"

```
var update_post = $("#post").val();
alert(update_post);
```

Comment: yes it was ID not a class sorry. I have changed it from . to # but it still doesn't work.

this is the original where all the WYSIWYG feature is working. It captures all the html formats

onsubmit="alert('You said:\n\n' + document.getElementById('post').value); return false;

but when i try it using

var update_post = $("#post").val();

it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: can you specify "it doesn't work anymore"? are there any errors, or it's alert with empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ".post", use "#post". A "." specifies a classname and a "#" specifies an element ID.

Your code would then look like this:

```
var update_post = $("#post").val();
alert(update_post);
```

Comment: yes it was ID not a class sorry. I have changed it from . to # but it still doesn't work.

this is the original where all the WYSIWYG feature is working. It captures all the html formats

onsubmit="alert('You said:\n\n' + document.getElementById('post').value); return false;

but when i try it using

var update_post = $("#post").val();

it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: it is a textarea where the class property of the textarea is javascript. I only need to get the value of the textarea which contains html format.

Comment: Textareas have no values, they just have .text() or .html(). Since the content is HTML you'd use .html().

Answer (score 0):

As I already wrote in the comments:

Textarea form elements do not have a value, you can get their contents through .text() (pure readable text as it is) or .html() (HTML tag and entity conversion for adding to the DOM). Though newer versions of jQuery already do this for you and get the contents of textarea via .val().

So you can either update your version of jQuery (mostly a good idea) or try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".update_button").click(function(){
    var update_post = $("#post").html();
    alert('Post is '+ update_post +'.');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: In jQuery .val() CAN be used to get the text/html from a textarea. Check the [api](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: so you are saying that i should change it from .val to .text() or .html() ? like this one var update_post = $("#post").text(); or var update_post = $("#post").html();

Comment: @Bas Wildeboer: depends on the jQuery version, and as it seems, the version he has does not yet support that (since the code is correct)...

Comment: @user1497888: Yes exactly, if you want to use the input to add new DOM elements you can use .html(), if it's just text like a comment or something, you'd best use .text()

Comment: @Simon True. Indeed the code is correct. Why not use a newer version of jquery?

Comment: @Simon, i just tried doing it but i don't quite get how to do it or maybe i am doing it wrong.

Comment: @user1497888: What version of jquery do you use?

Comment: @Bas Wildeboer I dont think it has anything to do with version, just checked it with jquery 1.2.6 and it works fine.. the code is up at jsfiddle .. please see my edited post

Comment: @Alice: true, works even with 1.2.6 if you remove the document.ready, however I encountered this problem once in a while few years ago, thought it's the most logic cause for this problem as I don't see any other flaw...

Comment: @Simon I guess the OP is using 1.5 anyway. And I checked it with 1.5 with document.ready and it works fine...

Comment: Yeah sure, document.ready is working since jQuery 1.3.2, I just wanted to test it with the oldest version available ;)

Comment: @user1497888: Have you checked if any js errors show up in your console?

Comment: i think i am getting the idea. 

1.) .val() does not accept html tags.
2.) when putting <?php echo $get_post; ?> as value in the textarea it would give the result of "Post is **[object Object]**."

Comment: @Bas Wildeboer yes it gives me **Post is [object Object].** when there is a <?php echo $get_post; ?> value in textarea

Comment: @simon, the alert says **Post is .** and the formatted html is not shown.

Comment: I really don't get this, can you give us the link to this page?

Comment: Yes I really want to see this page  now :-)

Comment: sorry but i don't have it yet live. i have it in my localhost.

Comment: i think @Alice your jsfiddle is correct but when i tried putting the class="uiwysiwyg nothing" it would give me some error alert.

Comment: tell me one thing what is the file name .. say is it "test.php" or "test.html" .. I know it is a stupid question but yes

Comment: @user1497888 can you post the class in jsfiddle save it and give us the link